# Does Apple's iPhone App Review Process use a business or calendar day?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

We are trying to plan our current and future iPhone app releases. I see that the app store claims 95% reviewed in 14 days as of 11/20/2009. I know this is an estimate but I was wondering if anyone knew if Apple was working off of business days (M-f) or are they referring to calendar days?

We waited 10 calendar days to get into review today. I can only assume the 14 day estimate starts with today.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on superuser, not here on the programming site...

Comment: Why? It's an entirely programming related question isn't it?

Comment: Sry, if this is in the wrong place. I am a developer and have been learning a ton about he app store and its behavior/process here. I saw the "appstore-approval" tag, so I figured I was in the right place.

Comment: I agree with @dredful.  This isn't something an iPhone user is going to know, but an iPhone developer would.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support, not a question about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: This question was relevant when I asked it 10 years ago and reviews took weeks and we needed to plan for that when developing our apps and planning/promising release windows. Today it is clearly no longer a needed/relevant question, but S.O. won't allow me to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple refers to calendar days.  I have had app updates and original submissions approved on the weekend.  And if they were referring to business days, they would have mentioned that.

***UPDATE by dredful (6/21/2012:***
While this answer was originally correct at the time, Apple's process has changed. According to the devloper.apple.com site, approval process estimated wait times are specifically referred to as business days.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. While the whole app store review is a big mystery, knowing that activity occurs on the weekends does help.

Answer (score 1):

Only someone from Apple could tell you how they calculated that statistic, and it wouldn't matter anyway. There's no way for you to know whether your application will be approved in  typical time, faster than typical, or lost in a tangle of bureaucratic red-tape for months (rare, but it does happen).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that your review status changed today from "waiting for review" to "in review", I think that the 14 days started 10 days ago, so you may not have much longer to wait.  (of course, you may not be one of the lucky 95%, or you may need multiple rounds of review, etc.)

Comment: David, it would appear that you are correct in your thinking that "14 days" includes the "waiting for review" period. We had another simple free app that was submitted and waiting for review on 11/18, went into review on 11/24 and now is ready for sale today 12/1. Hopefully our submitted augmented reality app will see such quick turnaround assuming it gets approved.